# How to fake QWheelEvent for tests?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt5.12

I need to make a test with googletest a function:

```
void SomeClass::changeSomething(QWheelEvent *event)
{    
    if (event->delta() > 0)
    {
        _data += _increment;
    }
    else
    {
       _data -= _increment;
    }    
}
```

How do I fake this event in order to pass the test?

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996997/how-to-simulate-mouse-wheel-events-using-qtestlib-qt5